# How to create meaningful features that allow unsupervised image classification?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, classification, image-recognition

I would train features that can later be correlated with categories, once I have some examples for the categories. Let's say one has a set of training images sorted by artist, and wants to create some kind of signature that will later allow unseen images to be grouped by artist, without having seen the images of the artist before.

I think if one trains a supervised CNN, one will get sharp features that match the known artists well, but may be completely random on images of artists that were never seen before.

Would it be a good idea to use a CNN and classify in the last layer with a sigmoid, but try to get it to create meaningful features in the previous layers that could be used to create a kind of signature for the artist, so that the hard cut in "Artist A/B/C/unknown" is only done in the sigmoid layer? How would you force the previous layers to learn diverse features instead of just fitting to the dataset of images with known artists?